# Laravel > Cartalyst > Sentry add remove permissions at runtime

Tags: laravel, cartalyst-sentry

**My Understandings**
I know we can add Group with some permissions and then we can create users with some permissions and finally we can add users to multiple permissions Groups. We can call these groups as roles as well. This is fairly simple.

**The Real Problem**
suppose we have teams and team members modules. A user "abc" is a member of multiple teams A, B, C. In team A the user's role is TeamLead. In team B his role is Assistant and in team C his role is NormalMember.

Now the problem is every one can see the list of teams. We need to display the Edit and Delete icons against each team. but only the authorise user can see the edit or delete link based on their role in the team inside a loop.

This is something linked with adding/removing roles or permissions on the fly.

Do you have any idea that how can I achieve this? how can I check permissions inside a loop with different roles in different teams.

Thanks in advance.

regards.

Answer (score 0):

you can check whether the group is assigned to the user and accordingly show the buttons

Also use has_access attribute of sentry while defining route. In this case you can limiting the access of route itself if user try to access edit or delete functionality through url